# How to calculate second-order variations of an action?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, action, variational-calculus

How does one correctly calculate the second-order variation of an action? I have started an attempt at the calculation (restricting the scalar fields for simplicity), but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Starting with the action for a free scalar field $$S[\phi]=\int\;d^{4}x\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\int\;d^{4}x\left(\partial_{\mu}\phi(x)\partial^{\mu}\phi(x)-m^{2}\phi^{2}(x)\right)$$ 
with Minkowski sign convention $(+,-,-,-)$. Naively, if I expand this to second-order, I get $$S[\phi+\delta\phi]=S[\phi]+\int\;d^{4}x\frac{\delta S[\phi(x)]}{\delta\phi(x)}\delta\phi(x)+\int\;d^{4}x d^{4}y\frac{\delta^{2} S[\phi(x)]}{\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)$$ Now, assuming that $\phi(x)$ satisfies the equations of motion (EOM), then the first-order term vanishes, however, I'm unsure how to calculate the second-order variation. So far, my attempt is $$\delta^{2}S=\int\;d^{4}x d^{4}y\frac{\delta^{2} S[\phi(x)]}{\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)=\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\\=\int\;d^{4}x d^{4}y\left(\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi(x)\partial\phi(y)}\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)+2\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi(x)\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi(y)}\delta\phi(x)\delta(\partial_{\mu}\phi(y))\\+\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi(x))\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi(y))}\delta(\partial_{\mu}\phi(x))\delta(\partial_{\mu}\phi(y))\right)$$ However, I am unsure how to progress (integration by parts doesn't seem to work as nicely in this case), as naively it seems as though the only term that would survive is $\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi(x)\partial\phi(y)}$, but I've seen references stating that $\frac{\delta^{2} S[\phi(x)]}{\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}$ is of the form $\frac{\delta^{2} S[\phi(x)]}{\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}\sim\Box +m^{2}$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

### Update

I have though about it a bit more and have come up with a general formula (for a Lagrangian with up to first-order derivatives in the fields) that I hope is correct: $$\frac{\delta^{2} S[\phi(x)]}{\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}=\frac{\delta^{2}}{\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}\int\;d^{4}z\,\mathcal{L}\left(\phi(z),\partial_{\mu}\phi(z)\right)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\\=\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(x)}\int\;d^{4}z\left[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi(z)}\delta^{4}(z-y)+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi(z))}\partial_{\mu}\left(\delta^{4}(z-y)\right)\right]\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\\=\int\;d^{4}z\left[\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi(z)^{2}}\delta^{4}(z-x)\delta^{4}(z-y)+2\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi(z)\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi(z))}\partial_{\mu}\left(\delta^{4}(z-x)\right)\delta^{4}(z-y)\\+\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi(z))\partial(\partial_{\nu}\phi(z))}\partial_{\mu}\left(\delta^{4}(z-x)\right)\partial_{\nu}\left(\delta^{4}(z-x)\right)\right]\\ =\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi(x)^{2}}\delta^{4}(x-y)+2\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi(x)\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi(x))}\partial_{\mu}\left(\delta^{4}(x-y)\right)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad-\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi(x))\partial(\partial_{\nu}\phi(x))}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\left(\delta^{4}(x-y)\right)$$ which, upon further integrations by parts (neglecting boundary terms), gives $$\frac{\delta^{2} S[\phi(x)]}{\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}=\delta^{4}(x-y)\left[\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi(x)^{2}}-2\partial_{\mu}\left(\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi(x)\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi(x))}\partial_{\mu}\right)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad-\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\left(\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi(x))\partial(\partial_{\nu}\phi(x))}\right)\right]$$ This seems to give the expected answer in the case of a free scalar field. Indeed, $$\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi^{2}}=-m^{2}\, ,\qquad \frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi)\partial(\partial_{\nu}\phi)}=\eta^{\mu\nu}\, , \qquad\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi)}=0$$ and hence, $$\frac{\delta^{2} S[\phi(x)]}{\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}=-\delta^{4}(x-y)\left[\Box+m^{2}\right]$$ Any feedback on whether this is correct or not would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A proper treatment (and how you should usually go about these things if you forget) is to remember the definition of the functional derivative. It is linear, defined to obey a chain rule, a product rule, and has the fundamental feature

$$\frac{\delta\phi(y)}{\delta\phi(x)}=\delta(x-y)$$

Thus, in painstaking detail, we have

$$\frac{\delta S[\phi]}{\delta\phi(x)}=\frac{1}{2}\int\mathrm{d}^dy\left[\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(x)}\left(\partial\phi(y)\cdot\partial\phi(y)\right)-m^2\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(x)}\phi(y)^2\right]\\
=\int\mathrm{d}^dy\left[\partial_{\mu}\delta(x-y)\partial^{\mu}\phi(y)-m^2\delta(x-y)\phi(y)\right]\\
=-(\square+m^2)\phi(x)$$

Thus, we can simply differentiate again to obtain

$$\frac{\delta^2S[\phi]}{\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}=-\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(y)}\left[(\square_x+m^2)\phi(x)\right]=-(\square_x+m^2)\delta(x-y)$$

Which is the desired result (note that $\square_x$ simply means that the derivative is only with respect to $x$ -- sometimes this matters)! Note that the delta function comes **after** the Klein-Gordon operator.

And that's it! No need to expand to second order or pull your hair out deciding whether you have to integrate by parts and when you can.

I hope this helps!

**B-B-B-BONUS ROUND**

This type of manipulation is actually extremely useful! For instance, in the path integral formulation, we have

$$\langle\mathcal{F}[\phi](x)\rangle=\int\mathcal{D}\phi\,\mathcal{F}[\phi](x)\,e^{iS[\phi]}$$

With this, we can use the above manipulations to find correlation functions! The key is to note that the path integral of a total functional derivative is zero. Thus, we have

$$\int\mathcal{D}\phi\,\frac{\delta^2}{\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}e^{iS[\phi]}=i\int\mathcal{D}\phi\left[\frac{\delta^2S}{\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}+i\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(x)}\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(y)}\right]e^{iS[\phi]}\\
=i\bigg\langle\frac{\delta^2S}{\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}+i\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(x)}\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(y)}\bigg\rangle=0$$

This holds for **any** action $S[\phi]$. In particular, in your free theory, this gives us

$$\left(\square_y+m^2\right)\left(\square_x+m^2\right)\langle\phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle=-i\left(\square_y+m^2\right)\delta(x-y)$$

Eliminating $\square_y+m^2$ from each side tells you that the two point function for a free theory is the Green's function of the Klein-Gordon operator. No need for generating functionals or all that messy second quantization.

Comment: Fantastic answer. I was making it way more difficult than I needed to! A couple of questions I have though: 1. One assumes that one can commute the variational derivative with the spacetime derivative. Is this always valid? 2. What is the exact justification for dropping the boundary term? I thought it was due to $\delta\phi$ vanishing on the boundary, but in this case one has a boundary term of the form $\int\;d^{d}y\partial\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi(y))}\delta^{4}(x-y)\right)$, I don't see immediately why this term vanishes?

Comment: To answer your questions:

1.) The variational derivative will commute with the spacetime derivative since they are derivatives with respect to different things.

2.) The boundary terms vanish because distributions like $\delta(x-y)$ and its derivatives all have compact support -- that is, they and anything multiplied by them vanish at the integral boundaries (this would still be the case, even if the integrals were over a finite spacetime volume).

Comment: Ok, thanks. In a heuristic argument for the $\delta$-function term can one argue that $\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi(y))}\delta^{4}(x-y)=0$ because $x^{\mu}\neq y^{\mu}$ in analogy to the identity $x\delta(x)=0$?

Comment: Exactly. The integral itself only has support on the point $x=y$.

Comment: Ok cool. Is there any way to show this explicitly? Thanks for the "Bonus Round" section by the way, it has proved very enlightening for me.

Comment: This is typically taken as a fundamental characteristic of the delta function. A mathematician would say it has "compact support," which is a property that is wanted specifically to avoid boundary terms. The delta function is not a priori a function. It is what a mathematician would call a distribution. Taking a look at books on distribution theory could give some insight.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58534/discussion-between-will-and-bob-knighton).

Answer (score 2):

In your first attempted calculation, there is an issue in the second line. Your update looks almost ok, up to the point when you say you further integrate by parts: at that point, your are no longer under an integral so you can't do that (indeed, you have already done the IBPs implicitly in lines two and three, yielding the $\partial _{\mu } (\delta ^4(z-y))$ terms). But this is not needed either, as the correct result is:

$$K(x,y) = - m^2 \delta ^4(x-y) - \eta^{\mu \nu } \partial _{\mu }\partial _{\nu } (\delta ^4(x-y))$$

which is the integral kernel of the operator $-m^2 - \square$ (as can be seen by computing $\int dx dy\; f(x) K(x,y) g(y)$ via IBP).

A different way of coming at the result (which looks cleaner to me, but that's just my own cosmetic opinion...), is to go back to the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Functional_derivative) of $\frac{\delta ^2 S[\phi ]}{\delta [\phi (x)]\delta [\phi (y)]}$, namely:

$$S[\phi + \delta \phi ] - S[\phi ] =: \int  dx\; \frac{\delta S[\phi ]}{\delta [\phi (x)]} \delta \phi (x) + \frac{1}{2} \int  dx dy\; \frac{\delta ^2 S[\phi ]}{\delta [\phi (x)]\delta [\phi (y)]} \delta \phi (x) \delta \phi (y) + o(\delta \phi ^2) \tag{1}$$

Note that this equation only prescribes $\frac{\delta ^2 S[\phi ]}{\delta [\phi (x)]\delta [\phi (y)]}$ up to *antisymmetric* terms: it must be completed by the requirement that $\frac{\delta ^2 S[\phi ]}{\delta [\phi (x)]\delta [\phi (y)]}$ be *symmetric* in $x,y$ (just like $\frac{\partial ^2 f (\vec{v})}{\partial v^j \partial v^i}$ is symmetric in $i,j$ for an ordinary function of $n$ variables).

So we must calculate the second order variation of $S[\phi ]$:

$$S[\phi ] = \int  d^4x\; \mathcal{L}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x))$$

$$S[\phi +\delta \phi ] = \int  d^4x\; \mathcal{L}(\phi (x)+\delta \phi (x),\partial \phi (x)+\partial \delta \phi (x))\\
 = \int  d^4x\; \mathcal{L}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) + (\text{1st order terms = 0 on shell})\\
 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial ^2\mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi ^2}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \,\delta \phi (x) \,\delta \phi (x)\\
 + \frac{\partial ^2\mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi \partial (\partial _{\mu }\phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \,\partial _{\mu }(\delta \phi (x)) \,\delta \phi (x)\\
 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial ^2\mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial _{\mu }\phi )\partial (\partial _{\nu }\phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \,\partial _{\mu }(\delta \phi (x)) \,\partial _{\nu }(\delta \phi (x))$$

Since the definition of $\frac{\delta ^2 S[\phi ]}{\delta [\phi (x)]\delta [\phi (y)]}$ requires an integral over $x$ and $y$, we introduce it by force now (keeping carefully track of the variable on which the various derivatives act):

$$ = S[\phi ] + \int  d^4x \,d^4y \;\delta ^4(x-y) \Big[\\
   \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial ^2\mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi ^2}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \,\delta \phi (x) \,\delta \phi (y)\\
 + \frac{\partial ^2\mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi \partial (\partial _{\mu }\phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \,\partial ^{(x)}_{\mu }(\delta \phi (x)) \,\delta \phi (y)\\
 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial ^2\mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial _{\mu }\phi )\partial (\partial _{\nu }\phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \,\partial ^{(x)}_{\mu }(\delta \phi (x)) \,\partial ^{(y)}_{\nu }(\delta \phi (y)) \Big]$$

Now we perform a few IBPs, in the variables $x$ and $y$. The boundary terms will be proportional to either $\delta \phi (x)$ at the $x$ boundary or $\delta \phi (y)$ at the $y$ boundary, and these are typically assumed to be zero when calculating variations. So we get:

$$ = S[\phi ] + \int  d^4x \,d^4y \; \Big[\\
   \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial ^2\mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi ^2}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \,\delta ^4(x-y)\\
 - \partial ^{(x)}_{\mu } \left( \frac{\partial ^2\mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi \partial (\partial _{\mu }\phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \,\delta ^4(x-y) \right)\\
 + \frac{1}{2} \partial ^{(x)}_{\mu }\partial ^{(y)}_{\nu } \left( \frac{\partial ^2\mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial _{\mu }\phi )\partial (\partial _{\nu }\phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \,\delta ^4(x-y) \right) \Big] \,\delta \phi (x) \,\delta \phi (y) \tag{2}$$

Note that we have used that $\partial ^{(x)}_{\mu }(\delta \phi (y)) = 0$ (that's why we had to somewhat artificially introduce a distinction between the $x$ and $y$ variables *before* performing the IBPs, otherwise we would be left with $\partial \delta \phi $ terms).

Now, for any function $F$, $F(x)\,\delta ^4(x-y)$ is symmetric with respect to $x \leftrightarrow y$, while the symmetric part of $\partial _{\mu }^{(x)} \left( F(x) \, \delta ^4(x-y) \right)$ is:

$$\frac{1}{2} \big[ \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} \left( F(x) \, \delta ^4(x-y) \right) + \partial _{\mu }^{(y)} \left( F(y) \, \delta ^4(y-x) \right) \big] = \\
= \frac{1}{2} \big[ \left( \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} F(x) \right) \delta ^4(x-y) + F(x) \left( \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} \delta ^4(x-y) \right) + \partial _{\mu }^{(y)} \left( F(y) \, \delta ^4(y-x) \right) \big]\\
= \frac{1}{2} \big[ \left( \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} F(x) \right) \delta ^4(x-y) - F(x) \left( \partial _{\mu }^{(y)} \delta ^4(x-y) \right) + \partial _{\mu }^{(y)} \left( F(y) \, \delta ^4(y-x) \right) \big]\\
= \frac{1}{2} \big[ \left( \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} F(x) \right) \delta ^4(x-y) - \partial _{\mu }^{(y)} \left( F(x) \, \delta ^4(x-y) \right) + \partial _{\mu }^{(y)} \left( F(x) \, \delta ^4(x-y) \right) \big]\\
= \frac{\partial _{\mu }^{(x)} F(x)}{2} \delta ^4(x-y)$$

and, similarly, the symmetric part of $\partial _{\mu }^{(x)} \partial _{\nu }^{(y)} \left( F(x) \, \delta ^4(x-y) \right)$ is:

$$\frac{1}{2} \big[ \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} \partial _{\nu }^{(y)} \left( F(x) \, \delta ^4(x-y) \right) + \partial _{\mu }^{(y)} \partial _{\nu }^{(x)} \left( F(y) \, \delta ^4(y-x) \right) \big] = \\
= \frac{1}{2} \big[ \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} \left( F(x) \, \partial _{\nu }^{(y)} \delta ^4(x-y) \right) + \partial _{\mu }^{(y)} \partial _{\nu }^{(x)} \left( F(x) \, \delta ^4(x-y) \right) \big]\\
= \frac{1}{2} \big[ - \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} \left( F(x) \, \partial _{\nu }^{(x)} \delta ^4(x-y) \right) - \partial _{\nu }^{(x)} \left( F(x) \, \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} \delta ^4(x-y) \right) \big]\\
= \frac{1}{2} \big[ - \left( \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} F(x) \right) \left( \partial _{\nu }^{(x)} \delta ^4(x-y) \right) - F(x) \left( \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} \partial _{\nu }^{(x)} \delta ^4(x-y) \right) - \left( \partial _{\nu }^{(x)} F(x) \right) \left( \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} \delta ^4(x-y) \right) - F(x) \left( \partial _{\nu }^{(x)} \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} \delta ^4(x-y) \right) \big]\\
= - \frac{1}{2} \big[ \left( \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} F(x) \right) \left( \partial _{\nu }^{(x)} \delta ^4(x-y) \right) + \left( \partial _{\nu }^{(x)} F(x) \right) \left( \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} \delta ^4(x-y) \right) \big] - F(x) \left( \partial _{\mu }^{(x)} \partial _{\nu }^{(x)} \delta ^4(x-y) \right)$$

So, identifying eq. (2) with the definition of $\frac{\delta ^2 S[\phi ]}{\delta [\phi (x)]\delta [\phi (y)]}$ above (eq. (1)), we get:

$$\frac{\delta ^2 S[\phi ]}{\delta [\phi (x)]\delta [\phi (y)]} =
 \left( \frac{\partial ^2\mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi ^2}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) - \partial ^{(x)}_{\mu } \frac{\partial ^2\mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi \partial (\partial _{\mu }\phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \right) \delta ^4(x-y)\\
 - \left( \partial ^{(x)}_{\mu } \frac{\partial ^2\mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial _{\mu }\phi )\partial (\partial _{\nu }\phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \right) \partial ^{(x)}_{\nu } \delta ^4(x-y)\\
 - \left( \frac{\partial ^2\mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial _{\mu }\phi )\partial (\partial _{\nu }\phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \right) \partial ^{(x)}_{\mu }\partial ^{(x)}_{\nu } \delta ^4(x-y)$$

**Check:** We can check that we get the same result (and that we get it much faster...) with Bob Knighton's method:

$$S[\phi ] = \int  d^4x\; \mathcal{L}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x))$$

$$\frac{\delta S[\phi ]}{\delta [\phi (x)]} = \int  d^4y\; \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi }(\phi (y),\partial \phi (y)) \frac{\delta \phi (y)}{\delta [\phi (x)]} + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial _{\mu } \phi }(\phi (y),\partial \phi (y)) \partial ^{(y)}_{\mu } \frac{\delta \phi (y)}{\delta [\phi (x)]}\\
 = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi }(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) - \left( \partial ^{(x)}_{\mu } \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial _{\mu } \phi }(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \right)$$

$$\frac{\delta ^2 S[\phi ]}{\delta [\phi (x)]\delta [\phi (y)]} = \frac{\delta }{\delta [\phi (y)]} \big[ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi }(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) - \left( \partial ^{(x)}_{\mu } \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial _{\mu } \phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \right) \big]\\
 = \frac{\delta }{\delta [\phi (y)]} \big[ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi }(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \big] - \partial ^{(x)}_{\mu } \left( \frac{\delta }{\delta [\phi (y)]} \big[ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial _{\mu } \phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \big] \right)\\
 = \frac{\partial ^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi ^2}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \, \delta ^4(x-y) + \frac{\partial ^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi  \partial (\partial _{\mu } \phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \left( \partial ^{(x)}_{\mu } \delta ^4(x-y) \right) - \partial ^{(x)}_{\mu } \left( \frac{\partial ^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi  \partial (\partial _{\mu } \phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \, \delta ^4(x-y) + \frac{\partial ^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial _{\mu } \phi ) \partial (\partial _{\nu } \phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \left( \partial ^{(x)}_{\nu } \delta ^4(x-y) \right) \right)\\
 = \left( \frac{\partial ^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi ^2}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) - \partial ^{(x)}_{\mu } \frac{\partial ^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi  \partial (\partial _{\mu } \phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \right) \delta ^4(x-y)
 - \left( \partial ^{(x)}_{\mu } \frac{\partial ^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial _{\mu } \phi ) \partial (\partial _{\nu } \phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \right) \left( \partial ^{(x)}_{\nu } \delta ^4(x-y) \right)
 - \frac{\partial ^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial _{\mu } \phi ) \partial (\partial _{\nu } \phi )}(\phi (x),\partial \phi (x)) \left( \partial ^{(x)}_{\mu } \partial ^{(x)}_{\nu } \delta ^4(x-y) \right)$$

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for your comments so far. I look forward to your updates concerning $\frac{\delta^{2} S[\phi(x)]}{\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}$. Additionally, I'm not completely sure why one can neglect the boundary terms? If you could comment on this that would be great.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. So for the boundary terms does one assume that $x\neq y$, such that the $\delta$-function vanishes? What is the justification for this?

Comment: I don't really need that: as far as the IBP in, say, $x$ is concerned, the functions of $y$ are completely spectators. For $\int dx dy\, F(x,y) (\partial^{(x)} \delta \phi(x)) \delta \phi(y)$ the boundary term is $\delta \phi(x) \int dy\, F(x,y) \delta \phi(y)$.

Comment: So the boundary terms vanish by virtue of being proportional to $\delta\phi(x)$ which is evaluated on the boundary and so is zero? (Sorry I couldn't accept your answer as well by the way, both answers are excellent)

Comment: Yes, $\delta \phi(x)$ is assumed to be $0$ at the $x$-boundary. (and I really like the other answer too ;-)

Comment: Is the situation similar when one derives the Euler-Lagrange equations , i.e. does one have $\int\;d^{4}x\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(x)}\delta\phi(x)=\int\;d^{4}x\left(\int\;d^{4}y\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\phi(x)}\right)\delta\phi(x)$?

Comment: You don't really need to introduce a 2nd variable at first order (when deriving the EOM), you have a term of the form $\int dx F(x) (\partial \delta \phi(x))$ so the boundary term of the IBP is $F(x) \delta \phi(x)$ which vanishes by virtue of $\delta \phi(x)$ being $0$ at the boundary.

Comment: But doesn't the first variation give $\delta S=\int\;d^{4}x\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(x)}\delta\phi(x)$ with $\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(x)}=\frac{\delta }{\delta\phi(x)}\int\;d^{4}y\,\mathcal{L}\left(\phi(y),\partial\phi(y)\right)$?

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but you can also directly identify $\int dx\, \frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi(x)} \delta\phi(x) = \delta S = \int dx\, \mathcal{L}(\phi(x)+\delta\phi(x), \partial\phi(x)+\partial\delta\phi(x)) - \mathcal{L}(\phi(x),\partial\phi(x)) = ... = \int dx\, \text{EOM}(\phi(x)) \delta\phi(x)$.

Comment: So is  $\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(x)}$ defined *implicitly*  through $\delta S=\int\,d^{4}x\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(x)}\delta\phi(x)$?

Comment: [Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Definition), that's the definition I like to use.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks for your help. Just one last question: is the second-order variation then defined implicitly by $\delta^{2} S=\int\,d^{4}xd^{4}y\frac{\delta^{2}S}{\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)$, hence why you did the integrals in your derivation?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the spirit of my answer.

Comment: Sorry to come back to comment on this some much later on, but I've been thinking about this a bit more and there's something I'm a bit concerned about. In the "cross-term"  of the second derivative, $2\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi(x)\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi(x))}\partial_{\mu}(\delta\phi(x))\delta\phi(x)$, it seems a bit arbitrary whether you write $\delta\phi(x)=\int\,d^{4}y\delta^{(4)}(x-y)\delta\phi(y)$ or $\partial^{(x)}_{\mu}(\delta\phi(x))=\int\,d^{4}y\delta^{(4)}(x-y)\partial^{(y)}_{\mu}(\delta\phi(y))$....

Comment: .... Depending on which one you choose to use this trick seems to affect the final result which is troubling. Surely the final result should be independent of this choice?

Comment: Oops, you are right! I forgot the requirement that $\frac{\delta^2 S}{\delta \phi(x)\delta \phi(y)}$ must be _symmetrized_ in $x,y$. Please see the edit to my answer. Then, as the arbitrary choices you mentioned only contribute antisymmetric terms, they do not affect the final result. Thank you for spotting the issue!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is it ok though to simply "drop" the antisymmetric terms? By the way,  how does one know that there are antisymmetric terms a priori? Does the anti-symmetry arise from the fact that $\partial^{(x)}(\delta^{(4)}(x-y))=-\partial^{(y)}(\delta^{(4)}(x-y))$?  Could one not first integrate the final term (proportional to $\partial^{(x)}_{\mu}\phi(x)\partial^{(x)}_{\nu}\phi(x)$) by parts first such that each term has a $\delta\phi(x)$ part, and  then use the trick $\delta\phi(x)=\int\,d^{4}y\,\delta^{(4)}(x-y)\delta\phi(y)$? ...

Comment: ... If one does this and then follows the rest of the procedure to end up with an integrand proportional to $\delta\phi(x)\delta\phi(y)$ then I think that the antisymmetric terms cancel out automatically.

Comment: If I am looking at matrices $A, B$ such that $\forall \vec{x}, A_{ij} x_i x_j = B_{ij} x_i x_j$ _and_ I _know_ that $A$ is symmetric, I can immediately deduce $A_{ij} = \frac{B_{ij} + B_{ji}}{2}$ ie "drop" the antisymmetric part of $B$.

Comment: Or, I can do an intermediary step, noting that $B_{ij} x_i x_j = \frac{B_{ij} + B_{ji}}{2} x_i x_j$, and from there deduce $A_{ij} = \frac{B_{ij} + B_{ji}}{2}$. I guess the extra IBP you are proposing would amount to this kind of extra step, and it is of course perfectly correct: it's just that we don't absolutely have to do it...

Comment: Ok thanks. How does one know that the cross terms are antisymmetric? Is it simply because it is proportional to $\partial^{(y)}_{\mu}(\delta^{(4)}(x-y))$ which is antisymmetric under $x\leftrightarrow y$, i.e. $\partial^{(y)}_{\mu}(\delta^{(4)}(x-y))=-\partial^{(x)}_{\mu}(\delta^{(4)}(y-x))=-\partial^{(y)}_{\mu}(\delta^{(4)}(x-y))$?

Comment: @Will I'm really sorry, there were a few more errors in my derivation. I have edited it again, let's hope that everything is correct now (at least, I get the same result as using Bob Knighton's method, so that's a good sign...)